# Could very minor impacts have caused electrical problems?

Tags: battery, kia

I've recently bought a 2002 Kia Shuma, and a few days ago I went for a 10 mile drive. I'm still learning how to drive, and I bumped into two kerbs, and while parking I hit a wall at low speed, at about 5-8 mph. No dents, just some scratches, so really not too serious.

After that I went back home and left the car parked on the drive for a few days. When I tried to drive it again, the central lock didn't work (so only front driver door can be opened), putting the key into the ignition has no effect whatsoever (no lights, no engine...). The car's completely dead and silent.

Is it possible that hitting two kerbs, and the parking incident, had such a devastating effect on this car? Would it be worth towing it to a car service for them to have a look? I paid very little for the car.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you left lights on, or the bump meant a door sensor was stuck open, leaving interior lights on? They are pretty likely. I've accidentally discharged my battery before by accidentally leaving the boot (trunk to US-ians) not quite shut and going on holiday for 2 weeks leaving the boot light on...

Comment: @lukasz  Rory has a solid point

Comment: So indeed it was apparently lights left on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything is possible, but small bumps and such shouldn't cause electrical problem like that.  All we know now is that your battery is dead or disconnected.  Pop the hood, and check to see the battery is still connected (i.e. the connections didn't come loose during a bump) Then you'll want to test it with a multimeter (if you have one), or just put the battery on a car battery charger.

If you're still connected, then there's another problem why your battery is going dead.  Check interior lights, car stereo, alarm, etc.  If you have a multimeter, you can do a drain check while the car is off.  (Test for current in-line to battery.)  The would tell you if something is draining your battery while the car is off.

Lastly, it's also possible (tho unlikely I think) that the battery has failed internally.  Maybe if it's a very old poorly maintained battery, would cause these problems... open the little plugs on top of the battery (if you have them) and make sure there's liquid in there.  Check for leaks around the battery area of the car also.